# TypeError: add_paragraph() got multiple values for argument 'style'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

при решении задачи возникла такая проблема
Вот код:

```
    from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
import sys

document = Document()
names = list()
place = input()
time = input()
for line in sys.stdin:
    names.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
for i in range(len(names)):
    document.add_paragraph(f'В', {place},
                           style='List Bullet')
    document.add_paragraph(f'В', {time},
                           style='List Bullet')
    for m in range(len(names)):
        document.add_paragraph(names[m],
                               style='List Bullet')
    if i != (len(names) - 1):
        print('\n')
document.save('Я туут.docx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `add_paragraph` принимает только два аргумента, а вы передаёте три

```
document.add_paragraph(f'В', {place}, style='List Bullet')
                             ^
                             Этого быть не должно
```

P.S. Зачем нужна такая конструкция `for i in range(len(names))`? Чего бы не просто `for i in names`?